# ggplot legend with geom_rect

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, legend

I am trying to create a legend item for a geom_rect legend. But the legends also shows a shape as well instead of a simple grey rectangle (see example below).

Is there a way to create a legend item that only shows the grey rectangle for the geom_rect and a filled shape for the data points?

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width))+ 
  geom_rect(mapping=aes(xmin=5.5,
                         xmax=6.5,
                          ymin=2.5,
                         ymax=3.5,fill="historic range"))+
  geom_point(aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width,fill="Data points",shape="Data points")) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("darkgreen","grey"),labels=c("Data points","historic range")) +
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(22),labels=c("Data points"))
```

Result with code above:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width)) + 
  geom_rect(aes(xmin=5.5, xmax=6.5, ymin=2.5, ymax=3.5, fill="Historic range")) +
  geom_point(aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Sepal.Width, shape="Data points"), fill='red') +
  scale_fill_manual(values="grey", labels=c("Historic range")) +
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(22), labels=c("Data points"))
```

[image]

Comment: This worked. I added a fill option to the geom_point layer so that the points would be in a specific color.